# Issue with category URL inside opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am having an trouble on main menu link of opencart. All the categories menu are displaying with non peramtereric links and one newly created category are showing link with `?route=product/category&path=207`. Please let me know how can i get rid from it and show like the others non perameterised links as `abc.com/bb-guns`. Thanks.

Comment: did you add the `seo_slug` for the new `category`?

Comment: At where we can add seo_slug.? @RohitBatra

Comment: this is screen-grab of `opencart v3` : `https://prnt.sc/inxt75`

Comment: Brother got it. Its fixed.

Comment: Can we be friends on skype.? If you don't mind.:-)

Comment: Sure, skype id: `rohit.batra99`

Comment: I sent request to you brother. With the name `Pankaj`